# Execute and Disown Process Remotely Through a Bash Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a Python program I execute on my Raspberry Pi but, I execute it through SSH. I want to write a simple Bash script that allows me to double click it and perform the startup which includes: SSHing into the Pi, cd'ing into the directory, executing the python file and sending to background, then using `disown -h` to be able to let it run without relying on keeping the SSH connection up. I'm using sshpass for simplicity and this is what I have so far but, upon running it, the terminal freezes, the processes run but, I know my program does not start up. What's wrong with what I have tried and how can I achieve my goal?

```
#!/bin/bash

$(
sshpass -p [MyPass] ssh pi@[MyIP]
"
cd Documents/MyProgram/;
python3 myFile.py &;
disown -h
"
)
```

Excuse my formatting, it's for clarity.

Comment: I don't think you need the command substitution here `$()`, also, you should use a here-doc instead of double quoting: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: @HAL9001 -- the ABS is the w3schools of bash references, outdated and full of bad-practice examples. Even when it's correct for the specific point you want to illustrate, it's better avoided in favor of [the Wooledge wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument), [the bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_documents), or [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't effectively disown a process if it still has handles on the local TTY. Use redirection to prevent them:

```
ssh pi@"$myIP" bash -s <<'EOF'
  cd Documents/MyProgram/ || exit
  python3 myFile.py </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
  disown -h
EOF
```

Redirecting to file works just as well -- the goal is to override the handles on each of your SSH session's stdin, stdout and stderr; that it's `/dev/null` is not so important.

Comment: This does the job perfectly, I can use sshpass with this as well and easily put it into a subshell within a bash file. The explanation is very helpful and it makes more sense now. Edit: I appreciate the fixed script as well.

Comment: As an aside, even when using sshpass, it's safer to put your password text in the environment than on the command line -- on most UNIX systems, command lines can be at least temporarily read by all users on the same system (programs can overwrite their own command line to hide sensitive data, but only after finishing startup), whereas environment variables can typically only be read by other processes run by the same user.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using the -e flag once I got it up and running.

Answer (score 1):

sshpass probably hangs on password validation. The safest approach is to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy private key to remote host and then use normal `ssh` command 
For no password login via ssh:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id user@host
```

then just use `ssh`

```
ssh user@host "nohup python3 myFile.py 2>&1 > /dev/null &;exit;"
```

you may use `nohup`

```
nohup python3 myFile.py 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still hangs up the terminal I execute this from. If it helps, the Python program stays running until I manually send a SIGINT or one of its brethren signals to it. The program does run, however, so I suppose that's some progress. As far as solutions go, terminating the command with SIGINT does what want it to, even if it is sloppier.

Comment: Adding exit does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: @AlexDiamond, ...if you still see your session staying open after you redirected all three of stdin, stdout and stderr, the place to look after that point is whether your `~/.ssh/config` is specifying any kind of port forwarding that might be holding connections open. If you have a `RemoteForward 127.0.0.1:10234 1.2.3.4:234` and your script connects to `127.0.0.1:10234` when you start it, that'll hold the SSH connection open until that connection ends; likewise for any other additional channel opened over the same SSH transport.